# ng-click does not fired inside compiled template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm trying to create a popover with custom html with angularjs and twitter bootstrap. Since this function has not been implemented in angular-ui, I'm trying to use bootstrap methods inside angular directive.

So I've created directive which contains such code:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  var templateData = 
    "<button class='btn btn-default btn-sm cancel' ng-click='closePopover($event)'>Cancel</button>";

  var compliedData = $compile(templateData)(scope);
  angular.element(element).find('a')
    .popover({html: true,
              content: compliedData})
    .on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return true;
    });
}
```

The problem I've got is that template is correctly added to the page, and popover works perfect. But `ng-click` method inside of compiled template does not fired at all.

What I'm doing wrong and how can I do it right?

Comment: provide us jsfiddle.

Comment: Do you have a `scope.closePopover` function?

Comment: @DanielDarabos yep. I've passed it from the parent scope and even created the new function inside the isolated scope. ng-click does not fires even in case I do just alerting: ng-click='alert("test!")'.

Comment: nope.code doesn't have scope.closePopover function. daniel is correct. put that function.

Comment: Please come up with working jsfiddle or  plunker...

Comment: Seems very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205250/popover-content-not-working-with-angularjs-ng-click?rq=1

Comment: @DanielDarabos yes! It is strange, but it works there (plunkr from your link): http://plnkr.co/edit/4uqGPvX1RNgDqKaSRz8l?p=preview

Comment: And works here: http://jsfiddle.net/cqf7koyn/

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Looks like I have a chance to implement what I want! But what if I want to inject function for ng-click from parent scope? I've forked your example, but it does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/a1carv5z/1/ Have I missed somethig there?

Comment: Oh, I've got it! I've forgotten to add attribute 'test'. :)

Answer (score 1):

`$.popover` makes a *copy* of the HTML you feed it in the `content` config attribute. Event bindings are not copied. Nothing to do except stop using bootstrap's `$.popover` directly and start using `bootstrap-ui` or something similar.

Comment: Looks like it makes sense, but in comments above I've got this link: http://plnkr.co/edit/4uqGPvX1RNgDqKaSRz8l?p=preview(from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205250/popover-content-not-working-with-angularjs-ng-click?rq=1). Seems like it works, isn't it?

Comment: Seems pretty strange, I'm 100% sure I tried this previously and this was the case. Just tried it and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/cqf7koyn/

Comment: I'd say something changed and the latest version fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

It is in [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover). It's a subset of Angular UI

For more information, in UI bootstrap, popover uses $tooltip provider.

so you can use custom html without any issue. It is exactly what popover does.

Here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/er8QHdJAsZzZWI2jGcW0?p=preview)

You need to have the following 2 directives

```
 .directive('xngPopover', ['$tooltip',
function($tooltip) {
  return $tooltip('xngPopover', 'popover', 'click');
}
```

])
  .directive('xngPopoverPopup', [

```
function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      title: '@',
      content: '@',
      animation: '@',
      isOpen: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'tmp.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.Hide = function() {
        $scope.isOpen = false;
      };
    }
  };
}
```

]);

The trigger is something like this

```
 <span class='btn btn-success' xng-popover='test' popover-placement="bottom">test</span>
```

Comment: AFAIK they haven't implemented custom html for popovers. This bug still valid (for 2 years): https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/1848

Comment: Yes,  you can. Popover is using $tooltip to implement. You can definitely do that. I have that in my project.

Comment: Wow! And how can I do it? Which property I should use to be able to add custom html with event bindings? Maybe you can show me some code?

Comment: HERE YOU GO ! I think using Bootstrap UI is a much better solution. http://plnkr.co/edit/er8QHdJAsZzZWI2jGcW0?p=preview

Comment: Including the contents of that plnkr link in your answer will help this answer to get out of the Low Quality Posts queue.

Comment: Sometime I feel like some people give -1 without good reason. I have pointed out the correct way. Even if it is not clear enough, it is not a wrong answer. If I am the asker, most of the time I just need some clues. I don't need the whole answer laying down for me. If I can't figure out, I would just ask for more information. After all, we are programmers. We figure things out.

Comment: @maxisam yep, somebody's -1 for your answer is unfair, so I've fixed it. By the way, after 4 days of investigation looks like yours approach could be much more useful. I'm trying to apply in to my project now.

Comment: Thanks. I used above code in my proj on production. It works for years.